# TinyMCE editor lost the focus of input box on popup dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

When I try to open the TinyMCE editor within a dialog box popup and click on "Insert link", the dialog box popup appears for "Insert link" but I am unable to write in the text field for "Insert link".

As far I know, the problem has to do with a dialog box open in another dialog box. Has anyone found a way around it?

Comment: Mind posting the code you are using on a JSFiddle or something?

Comment: actually i am using the jTable.org for CRUD and on edit popup i am append TinyMCE to it.

Answer (score 10):

I found the answer :)

```
$(document).on('focusin', function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest(".mce-window").length) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
});
```

just paste the above code and focus will bbe automatically on last dialog box of TinyMCE.

Comment: I have the textarea in a modal popup.  I had to put this code inside $('#EmailModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) { ...  (YOUR CODE) });  Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

i got another trick to solve that.. thanks to tyemmcee, see bug:
http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_view.php?id=5917

```
  $.widget("ui.dialog", $.ui.dialog, {
    _allowInteraction: function(event) {
        return !!$(event.target).closest(".mce-container").length || this._super( event );
        }
    });
```

see tinymce fiddle: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/lpdaab/2

Comment: does anybody have same problem?